# Tate Twists of Z/nZ

Tags: homology-cohomology, local-field, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be a $p$-adic local field with absolute Galois group $G_k$. In *Cohomology of Number Fields*, the authors define the $n$-th Tate twist of a finite $G_k$-module $A$ as the $G_k$-module $A(n)$ that is equal to $A$ as an abelian group and endowed with the twisted action $\sigma(a) = \chi(\sigma)^n \cdot \sigma a$, where $\chi$ denotes the cyclotomic character and the action on the right-hand side is the original action of $G_k$ on $A$.

I do not quite understand how the multiplication of $\chi(\sigma)^n$ with $\sigma a$ works. $\chi$ takes values in some product $\prod \mathbb{Z}_l^\times$, so how can this be multiplied with the elements of an arbitrary finite $G_K$-module $A$? More concretely, I would like to understand the modules $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}(i)$. It is claimed that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}(i) \cong \mu_n^{\otimes i}$, but I do not quite understand the cyclotomic action in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Once we know that $A(1) = \mu_n \otimes A$, this makes a lot of sense to me. Would you mind elaboarating why your definition agrees with the one I gave in my question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my definition of the cyclotomic character $\chi$, $\text{Aut}(\mu)$ is identified with $C := \prod_{l \neq \text{char}(k)} \mathbb{Z}_l^\times$, and $A(n)$ is defined as a $G_k$-module that is equal to $A$ as an abelian group together with an action $\sigma(a) = \chi(\sigma)^n \cdot \sigma a$. I was confused about how this action makes sense, given that it requires a $C$-module structure on $A$. But if I understand you correctly, you say that this is dealt with by identifying $A$ with $A \otimes C$ first, so the action then makes sense?

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense and completely answers my question (and sorry for the typos in my previous comment, I had indeed meant to write $\mu$ instead of $C$).